# How to count no. of select HTML elements present on a form in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've following HTML of a table:

```
<table id="blacklistgrid_1"  class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="vertical-align:middle">Products</th>
          <th style="vertical-align:middle">Pack Of</th>
          <th style="vertical-align:middle">Quantity</th>
          <th style="vertical-align:middle">Volume</th>
          <th style="vertical-align:middle">Unit</th>
          <th style="vertical-align:middle">Rebate Amount</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="apnd-test">
        <tr id="reb1_1">
          <td>
            <div class="btn-group">
              <select name="product_id_1[1]" id="product_id_1_1" class="form-control prod_list">
                <option value=""  selected='selected'>Select Product</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="pack[1]" id="pack_1" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="quantity[1]" id="quantity_1" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="volume[1]" id="volume_1" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
          <td>
            <div class="btn-group">
              <select name="units[1]" id="units_1" class="form-control">
                <option value=""  selected='selected'>Select Unit</option>
                <option value="5" >Microsecond</option>
                <option value="7" >oz</option>
                <option value="9" >ml</option>
                <option value="10" >L</option>
                <option value="12" >gms</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="amount[1]" id="amount_1" value="" class="form-control" size="9"/></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr id="reb1_2">
          <td><button style="float:right; margin-bottom: 20px" class="products" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="">&nbsp;Add</button></td>
          <td colspan="5"></td>                            
        </tr>
      </tfoot>                                           
    </table>
```

I want to count the no. of select present in that particular table id only .controls with class prod_list and adding 1 to it. Now there is only one such select element is present butit can increase. So I should get the updated count. I tried following code but it's always giving me 1.

```
$(function () {
$(document).delegate('.products','click',function (e) {
var n = $('select .prod_list ').length  + 1;
});  
});
```

Where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You have space in select and class selector which tries to find `.prod_list` child in select element. You should use:

```
 $('select.prod_list').length  + 1;
```

**Update:** To get select withing clicked elements parent(closest parent) table.

```
 $(this).closest('table').find('select.prod_list').length+1;
```

Comment: But as there may be multiple tables and multiple select controls in each table. So I want a script which would give me the no. of select controls in that specific table only from which the Add button is clicked.

Comment: You can use .find(select.prod_list) (as said above) for that table button click ..